# re-size image according to screen size automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple div and an IMG tag in it. The goal I have to achieve is:

Background image should be re-sized automatically according to screen width and height and no horizontal or vertical scroll-bars appear.

how can I accomplish this ?

------------------------------Code--------------------------

```
<div>
<img id="image" src="background.png" alt="Image not found"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `img { width: 100% }`

Comment: Do you want it scaled so it looks squished one way or the other if the shave of the window doesn't match the shape of the image?

Comment: You are saying background image ? so is it IMG or background image of DIV

Comment: I want to use CSS property (backgourd-image: ------;

Comment: @l_lser have you checked with my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below CSS

```
#containerElem { 
  background: url(...);
  background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```

and here `#containerElem` is the `div` or some element where the background is applied.